# Publish Angular 2 application

Tags: angular

Ok so maybe I'm being completely stupid here, however all I'm trying to do is publish my test project to my host provider.

These were the steps I followed:

ran: `ng build -prod`

Waited for the `dist` folder to be created:

[image]

FTP to my hosting provider, copied and pasted the content from the `dist` folder into my public_html folder on the server.

Navigated to the URL and I see nothing but a white screen with loading in the top left, 5 errors in the console which read:

[image]

Can someone explain to me what exactly I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you upload all files in the root of your public_html folder? And what is the base href in your index.html?

Comment: @OwainvanBrakel  I uploaded all files from my dist folder into the public_html folder on my server.  my base href is <base href="/">

Comment: Hmm that's really weird are there any rewrite rules active that would conflict? also is it possible to share an URL??

Comment: @OwainvanBrakel It's a simple site just been learning material.io so nothing exciting, sure here's the link: http://101.0.119.70/~activem1/index.html it has no rewrite rules what so ever

Comment: In the url it shows "~activem1" but index.html tries to load files from a base href of "/" could you try to edit the base href in the index.html to "/~activem1/"

Comment: @OwainvanBrakel that's the issue! thanks!much appreciated! totally overlooked that!

Comment: You can change the base href in your index.html source file so you don't have to change that each time you make a dist build, if that somehow conflict with your local server setup you can use the base href flag on the angular-cli build command: ng build --prod --base-href "/~activem1/"

Comment: @OwainvanBrakel base href flag on the angular-cli build command good to know for future reference, thanks for you're help.  Feel free to put together an answer and I'll mark it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

> Add the base element just after the  tag. If the app folder is the application root, as it is for our application, set the href value exactly as shown here.

The `<base href="/">` tells the Angular router the static part of the URL. The router then only modifies the remaining part of the URL.

In your case the static part of the URL is `site.com/~activem1/` so you'll have to pass the additional part of the URL in the base href.

```
<head>
  <base href="/~activem1/">
</head>
```

If you're using angular-cli to build you can easily add a build command to your package.json
`"dist": "ng build --prod --base-href \"/~activem1/\""`
when you run `npm run dist` the base href will be set by the ng build command.